# SQL Statement to get grouped data from every 30 days, grouped by date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, group-by

I have a table with the following two columns

```
ExportTime              | Manufacturer
2009-11-16 21:30:10.000 | IBM
2009-11-16 21:30:05.000 | VMWare
2009-11-16 21:30:12.000 | HP
2009-11-17 21:30:10.000 | Dell
2009-11-17 21:30:05.000 | VMWare
2009-11-17 21:30:12.000 | VMWare
```

I'm trying to create a chart to visualize the percentage of VMs over time.  So basically I want a SQL result that looks like this:

```
Date       | Virtual | Physical
2009-11-16 | 1       | 2
2009-11-16 | 2       | 1
```

This is the base query I've started with that gives me all virtual and all physical

```
SELECT a.vmcount, b.physcount FROM (
    SELECT count(*) as vmcount FROM ServerDataHistorical
    WHERE Manufacturer LIKE 'VM%') a, (
    SELECT count(*) as physcount FROM ServerDataHistorical
    WHERE Manufacturer NOT LIKE 'VM%'
    ) b
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(dd,(DATEDIFF(dd,0,ServerDataHistorical.ExportTime)),0) as date, a.vmcount, b.physcount FROM (
    SELECT count(*) as vmcount FROM ServerDataHistorical
    WHERE Manufacturer LIKE 'VM%') a, (
    SELECT count(*) as physcount FROM ServerDataHistorical
    WHERE Manufacturer NOT LIKE 'VM%'
    ) b,
    ServerDataHistorical
GROUP BY DATEADD(dd,(DATEDIFF(dd,0,ServerDataHistorical.ExportTime)),0)
```

And it tells me that vmcount is invalid because it's not contained in the group by clause.  I also tried this:

```
Declare @myDate varchar
Set @myDate = '2009-11-16'
SELECT ExportTime, a.vmcount, b.physcount FROM (
    SELECT count(*) as vmcount FROM ServerDataHistorical
    WHERE Manufacturer LIKE 'VM%' AND ExportTime LIKE @myDate + '%') a, (
    SELECT count(*) as physcount FROM ServerDataHistorical
    WHERE Manufacturer NOT LIKE 'VM%' AND ExportTime LIKE @myDate + '%'
    ) b,
    ServerDataHistorical
Group by ExportTime
```

I thought I'd just programatically step through dates and get the numbers, but this gives the same error as the last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic query would be much simpler with conditional summation:

```
SELECT sum(case when sdh.Manufacturer like 'VM%' then 1 else 0 end) as vmcount,
       sum(case when sdh.Manufacturer not like 'VM%' then 1 else 0 end) as physical
FROM ServerDataHistorical sdh
```

If you want this by date, just add in a `group by` clause:

```
SELECT cast(sdh.ExportTime as date) as thedate,
       sum(case when sdh.Manufacturer like 'VM%' then 1 else 0 end) as vmcount,
       sum(case when sdh.Manufacturer not like 'VM%' then 1 else 0 end) as physical
FROM ServerDataHistorical sdh
group by cast(sdh.ExportTime as date)
order by 1;
```

And, if you want this for a particular date period, just add in a `where` clause:

```
where ExportTime >= cast(@myDate as datetime) and
      ExportTime < cast(@MyDate as datetime) + 1
```

By the way, the variable @MyDate should be declared as a `date` or `datetime`.  Get out of the habit of storing date/time values in strings.

Comment: I stored it as a string since I only wanted a partial match, if that makes sense...

Comment: @ScottBeeson . . . Storing the values as a string doesn't really make sense (although I give you credit for using ISO standard date formats).  All databases have functions for pulling dates apart, such as `year()`, `month()`, and `day()` and for doing simple arithmetic (`datediff()`, `dateadd()`).

Comment: Looks like the results are what I need.  Thanks.